# width does not work inside flexbox using firefox

Tags: html, flexbox

Firefox seems really broke when it comes to flexbox.

I am looking at this web page, which claims to show the flexbox code that is supposed to run on all major browser the same way. So I downloaded the code and when I change the `width` variable FF 21.0 does nothing. But using Chrome and IE 10, it does change the layout correctly.

This article is supposed to guide someone on how to use flexbox so that it works on all browser.  The complete HTML and CSS code is  [here](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zlntC)   and the article is http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/  `Using Flexbox: Mixing Old and New for the Best Browser Support`

The part of the code I am having hard time with is the `width` below. If I change it to any value, nothing happens in FF.

```
.main-content {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;   /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;      /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
  -ms-flex-order: 2;              /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  -webkit-order: 2;               /* NEW - Chrome */
  order: 2;                       /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

  width: 60%;            /* No flex here, other cols take up remaining space */

  -moz-box-flex: 1;               
  background: white;
}
```

How to fix this so that FF will respond to changes in the `width` above?

Comment: _“Firefox seems really broke when it comes to flexbox.”_ – basically nothing more to add to that. I think there’s a flag in about:config that you can set for FF to use the “new” flexbox implementation, but that won’t help your users visiting the page. Flex-box is still not in a state that it is usable on the web IMHO.

Comment: Browser version is not useful on its own.  Is this a problem with the old 2009 implementation or the standard implementation?

Comment: this is fixed in firefox 22 beta. Just tried it. it works. changing width with % works. download FF 22 beta from http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/beta/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *lots* of bugs listed in Bugzilla regarding the 2009 implementation of Flexbox.  This is one of them.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=529761

> FF's css width, min-width, max-width, height, min-height, and
>   max-height properties do not work correctly using percentages % values
>   on two or more -moz-box flex elements. [...] Presently, there is no work around to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as a workaround, and it certainly is a work around...

It seems you should set a width on the container.

If I had:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
```

I could mimic the ability to set percentage widths on the children of the flex container by giving the container a percentage width (I prefer [vw and vh units](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)), such as:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 70vw;
}
```

Laying out the boxes inside is a simple game to find a good balance of flex and margin values... Maybe:

```
.inner-box1 {
    flex: 3;
    margin: [?];
}
.inner-box2 {
    flex: 1;
    margin: [?];
}
```